# Is the orthogonal complement always non-empty?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are given a vector space $V$ with $dim(V)=n$. Then if we have a subspace $W\subseteq V$ with $dim(W)<n$, is $W^{\perp}$, the orthogonal complement of $W$, necessarily non-empty (discounting the zero vector)? It seems to follow implicitly from the fact that $dim(V) = dim(W) + dim(W^{\perp})$, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Yes, as you say, $\operatorname{dim}(W^{\top})>0$, so any basis for it must contain a nonzero vector, assuming $n>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming $V$ is an inner-product space (such as $\mathbb{R}^n$).  Choose an orthonormal basis $B = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k\}$ of $W$, and extended it to a basis $A = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ of $V$.  Then perform Gram-Schmidt on $A$.  Check that in Gram-Schmidt, if the first $k$ basis vectors are already orthonormal, they will not be changed; so we get a new basis $A' = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k, w_{k+1}, \ldots, w_n\}$.  By definition Gram-Schmidt gives us an orthonormal basis, so the $(k+1)$-st basis element $w_{k+1}$ is orthogonal to the first $k$, which are the basis vectors for $B$.  So $w_{k+1}$ is orthogonal to $W$.  In fact, we get a basis $\{w_{k+1}, \ldots, w_n\}$ for $W^\perp$.